# Pattern for varying data structures

Tags: c#, design-patterns, file-format

I am working on a project that requires a fixed length file to be deserialized into an object structure.

The file has this basic structure:

-- file header data
----- groups
----------details

Normally this would be an easy task, however this particular file format has about 10 different sub-formats for the detail records.  For example, if the detail row starts with a code '7' then its format ABC, with vastly different fields than format XYZ (rows starting wtih '8').

So my question is, what design pattern could I possibly use to implement this in an elegant fashion?

My first thought is to make a generic detail class with a DetailType enumeration property, and also have a property of type IDetailSpec called SpecData.  IDetailSpec would really just be a marker interface.  Then whenever I worked with the Detail object I would check the DetailType property and do a cast on the SpecData property depending on the context.

This however, feels "wrong" :)

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: How you store the data is going to be dependent on what you actually need to do with it.  Without knowing what you need to do with the data a sensible decision as to how it should be stored can't really be made.

Comment: You probably want factory pattern, where the parameter to the factory is the format type, and the created type knows how to deserialize a particular type of detail record

Comment: @Servy All the data stored will be used in the application depending on the context of the operation at hand.  For example, there is a concept of returning a detail record, so we would have a MarkForReturn() method that would then change the detail record's fields.  The fields that get changed and what values to change them to all depends on the format of the detail record.  In other words, the operations are common, but how they get implemented vary by format.

Comment: @antlersoft That makes sense, but I am more wondering what the Detail class would look like structurally.  Would it be composed of sub-objects, one for each format.  Or would it just have one IDetailSpec data field, that you would have to cast depending on the format type.

Comment: @Digitalfront why are you speaking about casting? You're not supposed to cast ANYTHING.

Comment: @ChrisEelmaa Not supposed to cast anything, ever? In any situation or just mine?  My reasoning was you could have a property of a generic type that you could cast to a more specific type depending on the format at hand.  Not the best solution, but just throwing the idea out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making a base class that handles the fields that remain the same between all of the different detail types.  (The data that changes would "deserialize" into a single field, for now.)  Then you owuld have a different child class for each type of detail record and use a factory-type pattern to create instances of appropriate child classes based on the detail row's code.  Each child class would deserialize from the base class object's "detail data" field.

Comment: I like this idea a lot. Thank you!